# How to model a circuit with resonant inductive coupling?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, inductance, resonance

I need to model (write the equations for) a circuit with resonant inductive coupling, such as the one in the picture below.

[image: image from Wikipedia of a type p-p transmitter]

The picture is taken from the Wikipedia article on [Resonant inductive coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonant_inductive_coupling).

I need to write the differential equations that define this system and thus to calculate how much current flows through  ***Rl*** , given  ***Vs*** .

My problem is that I have zero clue where to start. I've only solved basic circuits so far (mainly DC). Even if I manage to calculate an equation for the left image (and perhaps solve it numerically), how can I use that for the right one?

My thoughts so far:
Using KVL for the first loop in the left circuit
$$V_s=V_{C_S}$$
And then applying this to the second loop:
$$ V_{C_S}=V_{R_S}+V_{L_S} $$
Then I substitued the formulas I knew for each component:
$$\frac{d^2 q}{dt^2}L_S+\frac{d q}{dt}R_S = \frac{q}{C_S}$$

Is my way of thinking good? Or did I neglect something that shouldn't have been?
And if It's good, after plugging this into a numerical calculator, how will I be able to tell the current in ***Rl***?
Any given help would be greatly appreciated!

Ps: I've already asked this exact question on the physics stackexchange site and this is how it went: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715431/how-to-model-a-circuit-with-resonant-inductive-coupling

Comment: Just note that, physically, one must add a serial resistor (eventually very "low") at input because a true "voltage generator" does not exist really. You can use also at input a "current" generator, then this resistor is not needed. Note also that the low "coupling" coefficient of Ls-Lr is "important" ...

Answer (score 1):

It is more simple doing calculations with Laplace equations (s -> t) or then doing s=i*2*pi*f for "sinusoidal" analysis.

Here is a Maple sheet as an example, sinusoidal analysis ... EE&O ...
(I forgot an "s" before M).

[image]

[image]

NB: the picture is for kc=0.2.